# Correct struct stat for my installation

Tags: 18.04, c, c#

As a learning exercise, I'm calling ftw using .NET Core interop from C#.

It works fine insofar as I receive appropriate filenames in my callback. However, I haven't defined `struct stat` correctly. There's a POSIX definition of that type, but it isn't sufficient because a particular implementation (e.g. my Ubuntu 18.04) is free to reorder the fields and add new ones.

I did the following search:

> find /usr -name stat.h -print

It returns quite a few results, and each of those files has multiple preprocessor directives.

`/usr/include/linux/stat.h` defines `statx`. I tried it, but nonsensical values were populated in places like size. It's the wrong one.

There's a definition in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h` that contains preprocessor directives.

Is there a way, given a particular Ubuntu installation, to definitively determine where `struct stat` is defined and what preprocessor directives were defined? If so, how?